# Find all integer solutions to the equation based on the following conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4$.
where $x_2,x_3 >0$ and $x_1,x_4 \ge 0$

I just know that the ans is $\binom{4-1+4}{4}$ if all the variables are just non negetive, but here 2 of them are non zero. How to do this?

Comment: One thing I don't understand, is, that why in SE people downvote a good Q and also when I have shown my working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Since $x_2,x_3 > 0$, this means that they are *at least* $1$. When we subtract $1$ from each of them, we get $x_1+x_2'+x_3'+x_4 = 2$.
Can you continue using [balls and urns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))?

Comment: @TobyMak I still did not get it...what is the final expression? U say it will not be $\binom{2 + 4 - 1}{2} = \binom{2 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1}$?

Comment: @amitayas  TobyMak initially overlooked some of the solutions but now agrees that you are correct.