# Arranging the letters of this word so that no two vowels are together

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> Arrange the letters(every arrangement must contain all letters of the word) of the word '**BENGALI**', so that no two vowels are together.

What my cute little brain could find out:
Let me first arrange the vowels...
__ E __ A __ I__
where the underscores contain the consonants. Now, clearly, there will be 
$^{3}P_3$ arrangements. So my brain tells me to find the ans for the E A I one and then multiply it by $^{3}P_3$
Now my brain thinks for a minute and then says:
 "Hey! There are $4$ underscores and how many consonants do you have? Its $4$ Is it not a modified stars and bars problem?"
I thought for a moment, and agreed with my brain. Then it said:
"Find all integer solutions to the equation based on the following conditions:
$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4$, where $x_1,x_4≥0$ and $x_2,x_3≥1$"
And the answer to this is $\binom{2 + 4 - 1}{2} = \binom{2 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1}$([just some honesty!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559845/find-all-integer-solutions-to-the-equation-based-on-the-following-conditions/2559848#2559848))
"But wait! There are $^{4}P_4$ ways of arranging the consonants. So multiply this by $^{4}P_4$"
And finally by $^{3}P_3$
So my final answer is
$$\binom{2 + 4 - 1}{2}\times^{4}P_4 \times^{3}P_3$$
Am I correct? If yes, is there any better or more efficient way? If yes, would you show that?

Comment: Your method certainly looks correct and I'd say it was optimal.  I suppose that someone could point out that using Stars and Bars, or the like, to count the number of $4-$ tuples of non-negative numbers that add to $2$ was overkill.

Comment: @lulu Please share if you have any other method

Comment: @lulu You want to say that I could have done it by the famous 'trial and error' method?

Comment: I want to learn any shorter existing method, so any post will be appreciated

Comment: More or less.  There are only two patterns:  either both are in one slot ($4$ ways to do it) or they aren't ($\binom 42$ ways to do it) .

Comment: What makes Stars and Bars hard in general is that with large numbers there are lots of different patterns.  That is not the case here.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for this, but you can post any better method also if you have

Comment: Oh, this was my only simplification over what you wrote.  Your method is better in that it generalizes more easily, but I always think it's good to do counts by elementary means if possible.

Comment: i understood that...i just asked you that if you have some new, better or shorter method, you can post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $4$ consonants, hence $5$ slots to place one of the three vowels. The consonants as well as the vowels can be written in any order. It follows that there are
$${5\choose3}\cdot 3!\cdot 4!=1440$$
admissible arrangements of the $7$ letters.

Comment: yup! got it