# Balls and urns when urns are indistinguishable

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can $100$ identical books be distributed into $10$ indistinguishable bags so that no two bags contain the same no. of books and no bag is empty?

My approach:
Though this looks like a simple balls and urns problem, it is not so. I would have easily been able to do the problem if it had not used the word **"indistinguishable"**.
We have the equation $$\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i=100$$ where $x_i\ge1$
So we can tackle this by replacing $x_i$ with $x_i^{'}+1$, to get $$\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^{'}=90$$ and then use $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$
But what to do with *indistinguishable*?
Edit:
So as "some SE user" told me to divide it by $10!$, I think the ans is $\frac{\binom{10+90-1}{90}}{10!}$

Comment: Indistinguishable means that “bag A containing x balls is the same as bag B containing x balls”. Consequently there will be less combinations. How many? Well: all the bags are supposed to have a different number of balls, consequently you have to factor out all permutations, i.e. divide by $10!$

Comment: @b00nheT So $\frac{\binom{10+90-1}{90}}{10!}$?

Comment: $\binom{10+90-1}{90}$ is indeed the number of ways of putting $100$ indistinguishable items into $10$ distinguishable bags.  One such example is $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+55$ and there are $10!$ permutations of that pattern; but another is $10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10$ and there is only one permutation of this pattern, so you need to exclude this and others before dividing by $10!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 10 bags are indistinguishable, the 100 books are identical, we may assume that the bags are arranged with respect to the their number of balls. Let $0< x_1<x_2<\cdots <x_{10}$ be the number of books in each bag. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i=100$$
that is, by letting $x_i=y_i+i-1$,  $1\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq \cdots \leq y_{10}$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}y_i=100-\sum_{i=1}^{10}(i-1)=55.$$
So you should count the number of [integer partitions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) of 55 in exactly 10 terms, that is $P(55,10)$ which satisfies the recurrence
$$P(n,k) = P(n-1,k-1) + P(n-k,k)$$
see [Integer partition of n into k parts recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908701/integer-partition-of-n-into-k-parts-recurrence)

P.S. Your problem is asking for the number of partitions of $n=100$ into $k=10$ distinct parts. The generating function of such numbers $a(n,k)$ is $$f_k(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a(n,k)x^n=\frac{x^{k+\binom{k}2}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^k)}.$$
According to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient(x%5E(10%2B10*9%2F2)%2Fprod((1-x%5Ek),k%3D1..10),%7Bx,0,100%7D)), $a(100,10)=33401$.

Comment: Can you please tell why my method is not working?

Comment: @amitayas Try to solve the problem with smaller numbers, say $10$ books in $4$ bags. What is your result in this simpler case?

Comment: No....sorry...i do not have

Comment: is b00nhrT correct?

Comment: If b00nhrT is correct, then the ans to the 10-4 problem you gave should be $$\frac{\binom{6+4-1}{6}}{4!}$$

Comment: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$.....$x_1^{'}+x_2^{'}+x_3^{'}+x_4^{'}=6$....if not indistinguishable ans $\binom{6+4-1}{6}$....if indistinguishable ans $\frac{\binom{6+4-1}{6}}{4!}$

Comment: No, he is not correct. There is just ONE case: $1+2+3+4=10$.

Comment: I learnt the $X_i-X_i^{'}$ technique from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559845/find-all-integer-solutions-to-the-equation-based-on-the-following-conditions

Comment: I am unable to understand the necessity of $x_i=y_i+i-1$

Comment: Please help me out!

Comment: $x_i=y_i+i-1$ is needed because each bag contains a different number of books. Hence, in order, the first bag has at least $1$ book, the second at least $2$ books, and so on.

Comment: oh! got it now....thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In effect, you are counting the sequences of integers $(x_1,\ldots,x_{10})$
with $1\le x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{10}$ and $x_1+\cdots+x_{10}=100$. If we set $y_k=x_k-k$, this is the same as the number of sequences of nonnnegative
integers $(y_1,\ldots,y_{10})$ with $y_1\le y_2\le\cdots\le y_{10}$
and $y_1+\cdots+y_{10}=45$. This is the number of partitions of $45$
into $\le10$ parts, or the number of partitions of $45$ into parts of
size $\le10$. It is the coefficient of $q^{45}$ in $\prod_{k=1}^{10}(1-q^k)^{-1}$.